# ManyToOne creates new entry in both tables for every new object

Tags: java, database, persistence, many-to-one, persist

I got City and Weather. Weather should point to the city objects in the database. A city can have multiple weather entries. My problem is that each time I add a weather to my db it creates a new city with the same name but other ID.

**Weather Entity;**

```
@Entity
public class Weather implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3562151396218034738L;
    private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
    private Float windSpeed;
    private Float windDir;
    private Float humidity;
    private Float temperature;
    private String weatherDescription;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id")
    private City city;

    public Weather(){}

    public Weather(LocalDateTime timeStamp, Float windSpeed, Float windDir, Float humidity, Float temperature, String weatherDescription, City city){
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
        this.windDir = windDir;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.weatherDescription = weatherDescription;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

**City Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class City implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String cityName;
    private String cityPostalcode;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private List<Weather> weather;

    public City(){}

    public City(String cityName, String cityPostalcode){
    this.cityName = cityName;
    this.cityPostalcode = cityPostalcode;
    }
```

**My two methods for adding weather to my db.**

```
    @Override
    public Weather addWeather(Weather weather) throws Exception {

        EntityManager em = JpaUtil.createEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(weather);
            em.persist(weather.getCity());
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (em.isOpen()) {
                em.close();
                LOG.info("New Weather entry for " + weather.getCity().getCityName());
            }
        }
        return weather;

    }

    @Override
    public List<Weather> addWeatherWithList(List<Weather> weather) throws Exception {

        for (int i = 0; i < weather.size() - 1; i++) {
                EntityManager em = JpaUtil.createEntityManager();
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                try {
                    em.persist(weather.get(i));
                    em.persist(weather.get(i).getCity());
                    em.getTransaction().commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                        em.getTransaction().rollback();
                    }
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } finally {
                    if (em.isOpen()) {
                        em.close();
                        LOG.info(weather.get(i).toString() + " added to db");
                    }
                }
        }
        return weather;

    }
```

My table weather:

[image]

My table city: (at the moment my weather data only comes from this one city, that's right)

[image]

Here a list what I tried so far (all i can remember of at least) and didn't work.

- cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST (now I persist both objects, otherwise I get "not marked cascade PERSIST" error)
- removing generatedvalue ID's
- without OneToMany (inside city) declaration
- only using ManyToOne without any specific declarations (like fetchtype)
- without join.column

That's all I can remember. If you need further information let me know.

EDIT:

I get my weather data from a webservice.

**My WeatherReader:**

```
public class WeatherReader extends RESTReader {


    private RESTReader client = new RESTReader();

    public List<Weather> getAllWeatherData() {

        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<City> citiesToBeCalled = client.deserialize(); // list resulting from deserialization
            ArrayList<List<Weather>> allWeatherList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { //TODO: replace 1 with citiesToBeCalled.size() to have all cities
                String json = client.weatherData(citiesToBeCalled.get(i).getCityName());
                List<RawWeatherData> rawWeatherList = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, RawWeatherData[].class));

                List<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int j = 0; j < rawWeatherList.size(); j++){
                    weatherList.add(rawWeatherList.get(j).convertToWeather());
                }

                allWeatherList.add(weatherList);
            }
            return allWeatherList.stream().flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**My RestReader.class:**

```
public class RESTReader {

    private String masterDataCityFilePath = "t.tmp";
    private static final String BASE_URI = "removed because of privacy reasons";
    private HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    private String mimeType = "application/json";

    //TODO: this is already good and can be used for the CityReader
    public String allCitiesAsJson() throws Exception {

        HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(BASE_URI + "cities")).headers("Accept", mimeType).GET().build();
        System.out.println("REQUEST SENT:" + req);
        HttpResponse<String> res = httpClient.send(req, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        if (res.statusCode() == 200) {
            return res.body().toString();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Status-code:" + res.statusCode());
        }
    }

    public String weatherData(String cityname) throws Exception{


        String realcityname = cityname.replace(" ", "%20");

        HttpRequest req = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create(BASE_URI + realcityname)).headers("Accept", mimeType).GET().build();
        System.out.println("REQUEST SENT:" + req);
        HttpResponse<String> res = httpClient.send(req, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        if (res.statusCode() == 200) {
            return res.body().toString();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Status-code:" + res.statusCode());
        }
    }

    public void serialize(List<City> cityList) { //Creating
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(masterDataCityFilePath); //(MasterdataCities)
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(cityList);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out
                    .println("Master data file saved under: " + masterDataCityFilePath);
        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.err.println("There was an error saving the file!");
            System.err.println("Wrong directory?");
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<City> deserialize() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(masterDataCityFilePath);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            List<City> cityList = (List<City>) in.readObject();

            in.close();
            System.out
                    .println("Loaded cities from: " + masterDataCityFilePath);

            return cityList;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an error loading from:" + masterDataCityFilePath);
            System.err.println("Wrong directory?\n");
            System.out.println("Directory is: " + masterDataCityFilePath);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getMasterDataCityFilePath() {
        return masterDataCityFilePath;
    }

    public void setMasterDataCityFilePath(String masterDataCityFilePath) {
        this.masterDataCityFilePath = masterDataCityFilePath;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:
my convertToWeather();**

```
    public Weather convertToWeather(){
            try {
                Weather weather = new Weather();
                weather.setCity(city);

                String str = lastUpdateTime;
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
                weather.setTimeStamp(dateTime);

                //assign wind speed
                String datacontent[] = data.split("#");

                String windSpeedValue[] = datacontent[12].split(":", 2); // specify data content number
                if (windSpeedValue[1].equals("unknown")){
                    weather.setWindSpeed(null);
                } else {
                    weather.setWindSpeed(Float.parseFloat(windSpeedValue[1])); //general just gimme the value specifier
                }

                //assign wind direction
                String windDirValue[] = datacontent[13].split(":", 2); // specify data content number
                if (windDirValue[1].equals("unknown")){
                    weather.setWindDir(null);
                } else {
                    weather.setWindDir(Float.parseFloat(windDirValue[1])); //general just gimme the value specifier
                }

                //assign humidity
                String humidityValue[] = datacontent[11].split(":", 2); // specify data content number
                if (humidityValue[1].equals("unknown")){
                    weather.setHumidity(null);
                } else {
                    weather.setHumidity(Float.parseFloat(humidityValue[1])); //general just gimme the value specifier
                }

                //assign temperature
                String temperatureValue[] = datacontent[9].split(":", 2); // specify data content number
                if (temperatureValue[1].equals("unknown")){
                    weather.setTemperature(null);
                } else {
                    weather.setTemperature(Float.parseFloat(temperatureValue[1])); //general just gimme the value specifier
                }

                //assign description
                String descriptionValue[] = datacontent[8].split(":", 2); // specify data content number
                if (descriptionValue[1].equals("unknown")){
                    weather.setWeatherDescription("unknown");
                } else {
                    weather.setWeatherDescription(descriptionValue[1]); //general just gimme the value specifier
                }

                return weather;

        } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error:" + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
    }
```

Comment: How are you setting the attribute city in the weather object?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple, for JPA, if your entity does not have any ID then it means that it will do a INSERT if ID is null and UPDATE if ID is not null.

From what I read, your city instance is always a new object or at least, an object not handle in the persistence context.

In your code, you should first check if there is already a named city in your database, if yes attach it this to your weather. If not just insert it (as you would have done in SQL...)

To avoid weird behavior I can also suggest to you to add a unique constraint on the city names.

Let me know if it solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Show the code in which you create Weather instances, that should be the problem.
The codes shown in your question do not decide how your data will be. Instead, they tell JPA: hey, jpa, please create a new transaction, translate these object state into appropriate SQL `INSERT` queries and execute them.

So, what decides your data in DB is state of object right before you call `EntityManager` to persist it.

Comment: I added the code how and where I get my weather data.

Comment: `
weatherList.add(rawWeatherList.get(j).convertToWeather());
`
show method convertToWeather() pls
This is the point

Answer (score 0):

Remove this piece of code:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
private List<Weather> weather;
```

I believe that this mapping in the City class is also writing the data to your db table. For ManyToOne joins, having the mapping one way should suffice. Compare this documents:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html
and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. Tbh I tested almost all possibilities with the @OneToMany(mappedBy = "...") or @Column(name="..."). I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/

I hope the article helps. Try using the inverse annotation.